# VHDL- library doesnt work

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, I am getting an error that library "work" does not contain primary unit "clock_div".Library being used is  "use work.clock_div.all;".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help you, you should really elaborate on you problem. For instance: you should tell us what program gives the error ("in VHDL" is not correct: VHDL is not a program...). Then show the steps you take in order to get the error. In the best case you provide us with all of the code, so we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiled "clock_div" into the working library?

N.B "Work" should not be a real library, it refers to the library you're compiling the current module into.

So if you're working on an entity that you're compiling into a library called "components", and "clk_div" is already in that library, then `use work.clock_div.all;` and `use cmoponents.clk_div.all;` are equivalent.

However when you later build the top level design, without specifying a library, `use work.clock_div.all;` won't find "clk_div" because you're not working in the components library, while `use components.clk_div.all;` will.